# using OR in Countifs[excel]

Tags: excel

I would really appreciate if someone could fix this formula:
=COUNTIFS(D2:D1825, {"Home improvements","Car","Other Purposes","Medical expenses","Business Purposes"},  O2:O1825, ">34", O2:O1825, "<78")

for now, it counts only the amount of "Home Improvements".I want to count them all.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
SUM(COUNTIFS(D2:D1825, {"Home improvements","Car","Other Purposes","Medical 
     expenses","Business Purposes"}, O2:O1825, ">34", O2:O1825, "<78")`
```

?

The issue might be that you are not summing the result of all the individual countifs. You can read more about this type of excel command [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/countifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic). Please let me know if that's not it!

#### EDIT:

@JerryJeremiah made a really good comment. He brought up the following points. I've changed my answer to reflect more of that. I've used some of his language. Things to note:

Why you don't see more than one result with the original formula even though there are more than one?

The array of strings the formula returns more than one value but if the formula is only put into one cell that cell can only hold one value.

I've entered the formula but it is not detecting the array. Why?

This is, as Jerry noted, a common mistake. You need to press Control-Shift-Enter when putting in your formula (that part always confuses people that haven't used array formulas before).

Thanks to Jerry

Comment: @Andrius If this worked, please throw it a checkmark, just so that I, and other users, know!! :)

Comment: Your answer is right, but it might be a better answer if you mention why you don't see more than one result with his original formula even though there are more than one (because of the array of strings the formula returns more than one value but if the formula is only put into one cell that cell can only hold one value) and that you need to press Control-Shift-Enter when putting in your formula (that part always confuses people that haven't used array formulas before).

Comment: @JerryJeremiah that's a good call. Things to remember for the next post. People should read your comment though. Actually! I'll edit my original post.